What measures are used to identify a faulty speaker?
I'm working on building a mobile app that would play a sound via speaker, record itself and process this recording to identify faults within speakers, what meastures or parameters should be considered that would indicate fault in speakers?

Faultiness in the sense of mechanical damage is commonly referred to as "Rub and Buzz" distortion. It can be caused by loose particles, rubbing of the voice coil on something else, voice coil hitting the backplate, wires beating against something else or partially loose parts buzzing.
It is usually impulsive and broadband, oftentimes low level and it is non-trivial to detect in an automated way. Also it is usually easy to hear and bothersome to the listener.
Classical harmonic distortion detection will do no good, as the rub and buzz nature is fundamentally different. It is an ongoing research field, hit Google with "rub and buzz detection" and do some reading.
